# Como executar uma query com grande volume de dados?

Tags: sql-server

Existe alguma forma de executar um arquivo com um grande volume de dados sem ser direto no `SQL Server 2014 Management Studio`, pois tento abrir para executar e obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível executar o script. Memória insuficiente para continuar
>   a execução do programa. (mscorlib)

```
Local do Programa:

   em System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Int32 cb)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.GetText(Int32 startPosition, Int32 chars)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellTextBuffer.get_Text()
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ShellCodeWindowControl.GetSelectedTextSpan()
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptEditorControl.GetSelectedTextSpan()
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptAndResultsEditorControl.OnExecScript(Object sender, EventArgs a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para estes casos, o jeito é usar o prompt de comando ou o Powershell e executar o script usando:

```
> sqlcmd -S COMPUTADOR\INSTANCIA -i .\MeuScript.sql -d MeuDatabase
```

Normalmente executo assim:

```
> sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i .\MeuScript.sql -d MeuDatabase
```

[Leia mais sobre o `sqlcmd` aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162773(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: No meu caso vou roda no servidor, o script tem que ser executado direto do servido ou pode ser de outra maquina ?

Comment: Pode ser de outra máquina. Você só precisa ter acesso a ela.

Comment: É uma resposta bem valida, mas como não tenho acesso, tive que transformar em um arquivo Excel e importar com o assistente do Server 2014 Management Studio....

Comment: Ah, sim. Funciona também.